# Saying something is like/not like something else

Tags: grammar, syntax

How does one say "this is like/similar to that" or "this is not like that" in Japanese in essence? An example sentence is

"In this way, the English are like the Japanese"

; I have not been able to find any materials detailing this (but a whole lot on how to say something is better/worse, which is not helpful!).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a few simple ways to express this.

> 「～～と（or に）+ [似]{に}ている」 = "similar to ~~"
>   「～～の + よう + です/だ/である」 = "(sort of) like ~~"
>   「～～みたい + です/だ/である」 = "(just) like ~~"

To use a slightly bigger word, one could say:

> 「～～と + [同様]{どうよう} + です/だ/である」 = "(very) similar to ~~"

For the negative forms of the phrases above, make the following changes:

> 似ている ⇒ 似ていない
>   です/だ/である ⇒ ではない/ではありません

Thus, "In this way, the English are like the Japanese" can be said as:

> 「これに[関]{かん}しては、イギリス人**は**日本人**に**似ている。」
>   「この[点]{てん}では、イギリス人は日本人みたいである。（or 日本人と同様である）」

Finally, if I am allowed to introduce a colloquial word that we use ***very*** often, I will mention 「そっくり」.　It means "just like" and you can say something like:

> 「その点では、イギリス人**は**日本人**に**（or **と**）そっくりです。」 or
>   「その点では、イギリス人**と**日本人**は**そっくりです。」

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this! I really wasn't able to find it either online or from textbooks, so many thanks for this thorough answer!

Comment: Would you consider ごとく on the same level as these?